How to filter a list of dictionaries on kinesis event source in Lambda?
Given the following payload being sent to kinesis data stream:
some_data = {
        "record": 12345,
        "order": {
            "type": "buy",
            "Location": [
            {
            "Country": "America"
            },
            {
                "City": "New York"
            }],
            "Day": "Monday",
            "stock": "ANYCOasdasdads",
            "quantity": 1000
        }
    }

How to create a Lambda filter pattern which only invokes my function when Country is America AND "City" is New York.
Doing some testing, I'm able to create a filter for nested dictionaries like below, however not for a list of dictionaries:
{
        "record": 12345,
        "order": {
            "type": "buy",
            "Location": {
                "Country": "America",
                "City": "New York"
            },
            "Day": "Monday",
            "stock": "ANYCOasdasdads",
            "quantity": 1000
        }
    }

Lambda event Filter used for above event:
{
    "data": {
        "order": {
            "Location": {
                "Country": ["America"],
                "City": ["New York"]
            }
        }
    }
}

It seems like filtering for a list of dictionaries isn't possible. Kindly suggest if possible?

Why is the first payload using arrays anyway? That seems to be an odd representation.
